# В Tensorflow не работает команда hello = tf.constant('hello') и не обнаруживаются gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda

Я использую версии

cuda 11.1

tensorflow 2.4.1

python 3.6.12

numpy 1.16.4

Не получается выполнить `hello = tf.constant('hello')`Возникают ошибки

```
2021-03-07 21:21:56.799062: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-07 21:21:56.800126: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.353810: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1050 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.493GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.43GiB/s
2021-03-07 21:21:57.353998: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.364724: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.364898: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.370873: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.372735: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.377804: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2021-03-07 21:21:57.382008: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.382892: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2021-03-07 21:21:57.384941: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-03-07 21:21:57.393327: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-03-07 21:21:57.393735: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-03-07 21:21:57.393849: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]
2021-03-07 21:21:57.394400: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще при при проверке оказывается, что TF не обнаруживает графические процессоры

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

---

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

Как исправить ситуацию?

Comment: `cuDNN` ставили? Вроде на её отсутствие ругается.

Comment: да, cudnn стоит у меня

Answer (score 0):

В PATH пропишите путь C:\cuda\bin

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]